# WebApi Routing not working for Post

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

My WebApiConfig has following routes

```
      // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The Post WebApi method has got following Signatures

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee emp)
    {
         .....

    }
```

When i try to call this method i am getting "Method not allowed"

If i change my Post method to following it starts working

```
    [Route("api/employee/post")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee emp)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I am not getting what's the issue. I want this to work with attributes routing. Can anyone suggest what's the issue here. Does GET and Post routes gets confused ?

Comment: Very likely you've faced the issue described in the http://brockallen.com/2012/07/12/beware-the-default-webapi-route-with-post-requests-and-a-route-parameter/ article. Add one more parameter as described there to your routing map.

Comment: That's a different issue. In my case it returns 405 error Method not allowed

Comment: what is the URL you are trying to use to do POST and GET ?

Comment: Api/employee/post and Api/employee/get

Comment: In your default route you are setting action = "get", due to this you are unable to call post api with conventional routing mechanism. Find below answer to work your api with conventional and attribute routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your default route like below:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //this enables attribute routing

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
); //this route is for conventional routing
```

now you can call your below API like http://{siteurl}/api/employee/  by conventional routing.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee emp)
{
   ...
}
```

now you can call your below API like http://{siteurl}/api/employee/post/ by attribute routing:

```
[Route("api/employee/post")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee emp)
{
   ...
}
```

Here [Route] parameter adds route, which is called as attribute routing.
You can find reference here [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)